# How can you compress images in a PDF?

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, compression, imagemagick

How can you increase the JPEG compression level on a PDF using batch tools under Linux?

Obviously you can use `gs -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` or `/ebook`, but that downsamples the PDF - it reduces the DPI. It's more efficient (in terms of how nice the PDF looks per KB) to use JPEG compression while retaining the same pixel count.

E.g.: https://docupub.com/pdfcompress/ allows you to half the size of a PDF yet when you zoom in it still has good quality, albeit with some artifacts. When you zoom in using `gs`'s `/ebook` mode, it inevitably looks more pixelated.

What Linux tool allows us to apply JPEG compression to each image in a PDF?

Is there any way to use ImageMagick's `convert -quality` on a PDF of multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

AS per comment here: [How can you compress images in a PDF (via a GUI, not batch or CLI util)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/732518/how-can-you-compress-images-in-a-pdf-via-a-gui-not-batch-or-cli-util)

you can try

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dColorImageResolution=230 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=compressed-output.pdf input.pdf
```

Tweak the dColorImageResolution variable - I could shove of about one third from the size of my PDF (but for degraded image quality, as expected).

Answer (score -1):

ImageMagick's built-in **`convert`** can operate on PDFs:

```
convert -density 300 input.pdf -quality 30 output.pdf
```

---

Unfortunately `quality` does not seem to be recognized when adding other arguments such as `threshold` and fails to compress PDFs created by ImageMagick, e.g.:

```
convert -density 300 input.pdf -threshold 60% - | convert - -quality 30 output.pdf
```

fails - it produces three copies of each old page on each new page.

If you know how to work around this, please let me know.

Comment: `convert` essentially turns the entire PDF into a single JPEG image, embedded into a PDF. I don't think that's what the question asker wanted to do.